# JavaFX exe wont run

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, exe

I have recently finished building a mini-app using IntelliJ IDEA in javaFx. It is my first time using this ide and language, so I am having difficulties manufacturing an exe file. I watched all sorts of youtube videos and different methods.
It does generate an exe file but when I click it, nothing happens.
Any idea?

Comment: Depends on how you're building the executable.

Comment: @Makoto Project Structure->Artifacts->Add JavaFX Application->From modules
Then in the Java FX tab, I set the Main Class to my main and build the artifact through the build option located at the bar at the top.

Comment: With the IDE you [generate the jar fx archive](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html) which you run via `java -jar` command, or [Jar Application Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-jar.html). IDE does not create executable (.exe) file.

Answer (score 1):

I do know that with IntelliJ Ultimate edition you can build down with an EXE file.
There are a couple things you need to double check.

First, is that in your project structure under artifacts, you have the "Type:" set to JavaFx Application(which is on the top right of the window).

Secondly, switch to the Java FX tab and make sure Application class is set to your main class.

Thirdly, Select "all" under Native bundle: which is located towards the bottom of the window.

[image: artifacts window]

Lastly, Select the Output Layout tab and move all your available elements to output root then click on the module of your application and look at the settings that appear at the bottom. "Make sure that main class setting is in fact the main class to your application.

Side note: make sure you delete your artifacts build folder just to start from a clean slate. Also make sure your Environment variables are set to the system path correctly.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying to click on the module to see if the main class is set correctly, but it doesn't in the screen. I mean I just can see Manifest file field and not the others that are below this field. can u please help me? what should I do?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad Java-FX Packager was removed after Java 10, The method above is for java 8-10. Post a screenshot for me to better assist you. I'm not entirely sure what it is that you are having troubles with.